# how to update a table with multiple cases when condition must be satisfied accessing another table?

Tags: mysql

### The problem is here:

By using the case clause, write a SQL statement that represents the following update:
“Add +4 to the total credits of each student who has taken satisfactory, i.e., with grade value at least ‘B+’, the Computer Science course identifier ‘CS-347’; add +3, if the student has passed the exam with the grade ‘B’ or ‘C+’; and finally add -3 if the student did not pass the exam (i.e., grade is ‘F’)”.

### My guess is:

```
UPDATE student as S
SET S.tot_cred = CASE
WHEN (SELECT grade
     FROM takes as T
     WHERE T.ID = S.ID) = ('B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+') 
     OR (SELECT course_id
     FROM takes as T
     WHERE T.ID = S.ID) = 'CS-347'
     THEN tot_cred + 4
WHEN (SELECT grade
     FROM takes as T
     WHERE T.ID = S.ID) = ('C+', 'B')
     THEN tot_cred + 3
WHEN (SELECT grade
     FROM takes as T
     WHERE T.ID = S.ID) = 'F'
THEN tot_cred - 3
END
```

---

However, I get the error message: **#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` expressions return a single value. So you need to put the logic on the `CASE` to see what value you need.

So like this:

```
CASE WHEN grade IN ('B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+') THEN +4
     WHEN grade IN ('C+', 'B') THEN +3
     ELSE -3
END
```

Your final query should be a `JOIN` where you get the total of credit for all the `TAKES`

```
UPDATE student as S
JOIN (SELECT T.ID, SUM ( CASE WHEN grade IN ('B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+') THEN +4
                              WHEN grade IN ('C+', 'B') THEN +3
                              ELSE -3
                         END ) as total_credits
      FROM Takes as T
      GROUP BY T.ID -- all the grades for the student
     ) as T
   ON S.ID = T.ID
SET S.tot_cred =  S.tot_cred + T.total_credits
```

Comment: Thank you! There is only a thing that instead of ELSE statement, it should be about F grade only cause there are Ds and Cs. It helped!

Comment: @SergeyKim I see ... My grade system is 1 to 20 so I wouldn't know ;). But glad you solve it.